# is it possible to see jenkins jdk install progress

Tags: jenkins

I am config jdk 11 in jenknins 2.235.3 running in kubernetes v1.16 cluster, I just want to know if it has a way to see the jdk install progress? so I could know if the config is correct or other problem. But now I do not know weather the installing is working. this is my jenkins jdk config:

[image]